# What does [=] mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to know what `[=]` does? Here's a short example

```
template <typename T>
std::function<T (T)> makeConverter(T factor, T offset) {
    return [=] (T input) -> T { return (offset + input) * factor; };
}

auto milesToKm = makeConverter(1.60936, 0.0);
```

How would the code work with `[]` instead of `[=]`?

I assume that

```
std::function<T (T)>
```

means an function prototype which gets `(T)` as argument and return type `T`?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The `[=]` you're referring to is part of the *capture list* for the lambda expression. This tells C++ that the code inside the lambda expression is initialized so that the lambda gets a copy of all the local variables it uses when it's created. This is necessary for the lambda expression to be able to refer to `factor` and `offset`, which are local variables inside the function.

If you replace the `[=]` with `[]`, you'll get a compiler error because the code inside the lambda expression won't know what the variables `offset` and `factor` refer to. Many compilers give good diagnostic error messages if you do this, so try it and see what happens!

Comment: "This is necessary"  - this exact option isn't necessary; we could also write `[&]`, `[=offset, =input]`, etc.

Comment: @M.M - Doesn't that capture references to locals?

Comment: @M.M. Using a reference capture here would be a problem because those local variables' lifetimes will end as soon as the lambda is returned. You're right that we could list the individual variables individually, though.

Answer (score 51):

It's a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) capture list. Makes variables available for the lambda. You can use `[=]` which copies by value, or `[&]` which passes by reference.

Comment: You can also use `[]` which doesn't capture anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use comment to provide this information, but I have too low reputation.

In cpp20 using [=] is now deprecated - use [=, this] instead.

More information here: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0806r2.html

As it is stated on this website
"The change does not break otherwise valid C++20 code, and the earliest revision in which a breakage from C++17 could appear is C++23."

So while using cpp20 use it like this:

- [=] → [=,  this]: local variables by value, class members by reference
- [=] → [=, *this]: everything by value
- [&] → [&,  this]: everything by reference
- [&] → [&, *this]: (this would be unusual)